# How do I handle Express.js routes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've generated Express app. I have an index page, I want to add subscribe form for collecting email form the save index page.

So I added a function to ./routes/index.js:

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
};

exports.subscribe = function(req, res){
    res.send('Subscribed');
};
```

Here's app.js:

```
var routes = require('./routes');
//Some code here
app.post('/subscribe', routes.subscribe);
```

Is that a good way to organise code? I mean, where should I place route handler in such case?

Comment: Yes, that's a good way. I usually keep one routes file per "controller", for example if doing  a blog web site: userRoutes.js for user functionality, blogRoutes.js for blog entries functionalty, adminRoutes.js for admin functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do some thing like

```
app.use(app.router);
var routes = require('./routes')(app);
```

and then create route.js, which may look like

```
var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
module.exports = function(app){
app.get('/',index.index);
app.get('/homePage',users.homePage);
};
```

now as you can see i have created a routes folder to manage all my routes such as index and users. So you can just have a look at the index.js

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
};
```

I mean that's the simplest and you can have get or post as per your requirement. This is the standard which you might see everywhere.

Comment: When I call var routes = require('./routes') does it load all function definitions inside ./routes folder?

Comment: no you have to do something like this, **var routes = require('./routes')(app);** then its gonna pass the required objects to other routes just a minor correction in last comment that i made. `var index = require('./routes/index');
var user = require('./routes/user');
var bootstrap = require('./routes/bootstrap');

module.exports = function(app){
 app.get('/',index.index);
 app.get('/cookiePage',bootstrap.cookiePage);
 app.get('/counter',bootstrap.counter);
        app.get('/msession',bootstrap.msession);
};
`